# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

Tags: javascript, typeerror

He's the JavaScript that's giving me an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null"

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"),rIndex;

for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
{
    table.rows[i].onclick = function()
    {
        rIndex = this.rowIndex;
        console.log(rIndex);

        document.getElementById("id").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("nome").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("morada").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("localidade").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("telefone").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("codpostal").value = this.cells[5].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("email").value = this.cells[6].innerHTML;
    };
}


// edit the row
function editRow()
{
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("id").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("morada").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("localidade").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("telefone").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[5].innerHTML = document.getElementById("codpostal").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[6].innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value;
}
```

What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: The error means that `table` is `null`, which in turn means that there is no element in the DOM whose id is "table". One very common cause of this problem would be placing that script code *before* the actual table appears in the document.

Comment: In which line did you get the error?

Comment: In line number 3.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah I've seen the source code and the javascript is before the table. I'll try changing that.

Comment: Yeah, putting javascript before the element makes the script to execute before the browser loads the element

Comment: @Pointy After doing that I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined

Answer (score 6):

There was no element with id "table" in the document, so

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"),rIndex;
```

table is null.